# Button such as stopShow(), previous and next won't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

So I recreated a slideshow for the class's assignment. However, the only button that works for me is the cycle(). The stopShow(), previous and next do not work for the code. This is what the professor showed us on the powerpoint. I've looked and researched, a lot of people tend to use stopSlideShow, pause button more. I'm slightly confused of which one is the most common use for webpage. I'm still new to Javascripts, so please help. :)

```js
var imgArray = new Array();
var index = 0;
var myVar;

function cycle() {
  document.getElementById("banner").src = imgArray[index].src;
  document.getElementById("slideNum").innerHTML = index + 1;
  index++;
  if (index > 5) {
    index = 0;
  }
  myVar = setTimeout("cycle()", 3000);
  return;
}



function previous() {
  stopSlideShow();
  document.getElementById("banner").src = imgArray[index].src;
  document.getElementById("slideNum").innerHTML = indexx - 1;
  index = index - 1;
  if (index < 0) {
    index = 5;
  }
}

function next() {
  stopSlideShow();
  document.getElementById("banner").src = imgArray[index].src;
  document.getElementById("slideNum").innerHTML = index + 1;
  index = index + 1;
  if (index < 0) {
    index = 5;
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="cycle();">Start Automatic Slide Show</button>
<button onclick="stopSlideShow();">Stop Automatic Slide Show</button>
<br>
<button onclick="previous();"> Previous </button>
<button onclick="next();"> Next</button>
```

Comment: I actually don't see a StopSlideShow function. Can you provide that function as well?

Comment: There are a few things to look at. Your `previous()` function references a variable `indexx` which appears to be a typo. Both your `next()` and `previous()` functions use a conditional `if index < 0` -- these should be different (hint: next is looking to see if next index value exceeds index maximum, and previous is looking to see if the new value is less than index minimum). Also, I don't see the `stopSlideShow()` function in the code you provided.

Comment: function stopSlideShow(){
            clearTimeout(setTimeout);
        }

   is what I put as for function stopSlideShow()